# How can I figure out why gnome-panel is frequently misbehaving?

Tags: gnome, debugging, gnome-panel

On my system (Debian Lenny AMD64), `gnome-panel` seems to act up now and again. I've not found a way to force it to happen, but it seems to be related to launching processes. Basically, I launch some process, and I see 1 core max itself out, and the taskbar freezes. I `pkill gnome-panel`, the taskbar reappears, and everything is ok. If I don't notice it, eventually my entire computer freezes and I have to hard boot.

How would I go about getting some kind of information on why this is happening that could help me or developers? Is there a debug build or something I could run?

Comment: I have a similar question on  another site http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/787/how-can-i-find-out-what-is-causing-my-gnome-panel-to-freeze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try taking a look at the **~/.xsession-errors** file. If you're lucky you might find some failed assertion or error in there.

You could also install the gnome-panel-dbg package and attach  gdb to the running panel to get a backtrace in case of crash (more information [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/gnome-bugsquad@gnome.org/msg00093.html)).